# How can I send alert to external user on any change in the list item value in SharePoint online List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, office-365, jquery-ajax

How to send alert to **external user** on any change in SharePoint list item because list contain more then 32 columns?

Is there any better approach (OOB) other than comparing individual value using jquery?

Comment: Every list has ootb  "Alerts" option you only have to subscribe with the desire option... Go to list and choose library ribbon. Then look for Alerts->'Set alerts for this list' and fill this form...

Comment: I need to send alert to external user.How is it possible using OOTB?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the list->List->Alert Me->Set Alert on this list, then set it like the below:
[image]

Comment: I need to send alert to external user.How is it possible using OOTB?

Comment: Yes, it also works for external users in SharePoint online.